# ode question in C^1 condtion.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\Omega$ be an open set and $f\in C^1(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^n)$ be a function. For $(\xi,\eta)\in\Omega$ consider the Cauchy problem

$$y'(x)=f(x,y(x));\ y(\xi)=\eta$$

Because of the $C^1$ condition this problem has a unique solution for some interval $I_{\xi\eta}$ which contain $\xi$.

Now fix a point $(x_0,y_0)\in\Omega$, for some $\delta>0$, the solution $y_{x_0y_0}$ is defined on the inteval $I=[x-\delta,x+\delta]$. if $(\xi,\eta)\in \Omega$ is a point such tha
$|\xi-x_0|+|\eta-y_0|<r$ for some small enough $r>0$, the solution $y_{\xi\eta}$ is also defined on the same inteval $I=[x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]$. I.e we can assume that $I_{\xi,\eta}=I$ for all such $\xi$ and $\eta$, and for some small enough $\delta$.

Here is my question, can we say for $(x_0,y_0)\in \Omega$, there is $h>0$ such that $|y_{\xi\eta}-y_0|\leq h$ for all $x\in I$ and for all $(\xi,\eta)\in \Omega$ such that $|\xi-x_0|+|\eta-y_0|<r$ for some small $r>0$?

Actually my lecture note use this fact without proof, but I don't know how to verify this fact. please give me some idea.